# TCP Client Multiconnect in loop

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, client-server

Hello i need i way to make client connect evry time & wait the server
   until will be ready & connect to him .
   i try diferent ways & i put socket inside while(true) but not connect
   eatch time . when i check network i see just  just one SYN_SENT  &
   closed  .

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      EditText ip;
      EditText port;
      EditText message;
      Button butt;
      TextView txtvew;
      String finalx;
      int tr;
      private boolean connected = false;    
      Socket so;    
      DataOutputStream inx;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ip = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        port = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        message = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        butt = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        txtvew = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tr = 1;   
        t.start();  
      } 
      Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
          @Override  
          public void run() {   
            try {    
             while (true) {
                    so = new Socket("192.168.30.18", 4000);    
                if (so.isConnected()) {    
                  connected = true;    
                }    
                while (connected) {   
                  try {    
                    inx = new DataOutputStream(so.getOutputStream());
                    finalx = message.getText().toString();    
                    inx.writeBytes(finalx);
                    inx.flush();
                    txtvew.setText(finalx);    
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                  }   
                }    
                so.close();   
              }    
            } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
              connected = false;
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }
```

Comment: There is not much good code in your post. And your app will crash. And you can find info in logcat. Further it is unclear what your client should do.

Comment: realy i am dispointed i think stackoverflow is the best but no problem i will search my self in other forum thx